# What is the maximum number of literals that can be used in a formula involving n atomic variables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An atomic variable or its complement is known as a literal. If we have $n$ atomic variables then we have $2n$ literals available to write a formula. At the same time, there are $2^n$ assignments in a truth table of any formula. To write the formula in either CNF or DNF would require $\frac{2^n}{2}$ assignments. Since there were $n$ atomic variables to begin with, we would have $(n)(\frac{2^n}{2})$ literals in the formula.

But does this way of presenting a formula in either CNF or DNF ensure the maximum number of literals that can be used in any which way a formula can be written?

Comment: I think I am wrong to say that "To write the formula in either CNF or DNF would require $\frac{2^n}{2}$ assignments."

Comment: And the maximum number of literals in a formula would imply that under all possible assignments, same value T or F is achieved. This would mean that the maximum number of literals that a formula could use in this case would be $(n)(2^n)$.